# Box plot problems

Tags: r, data-visualization, boxplot

I'm pretty new to statistics, but I'm using R to create some charts for my masters dissertation. So far I've created a box plot, however, when said box plot looks like this, which I'm 90% certain isn't correct.

[image]

The code I used for this is as follows:

```
boxplot(Pollinators~Year, data=X_east_pool_park_realistic_results,
        main=toupper("Pollinators per Year"), font.main=3, cex.main=1.2,
        xlab="Year", ylab="Pollinators", font.lab=3, col="white")
```

I'm sure this has a really easy solution that I just haven't managed to come across, but as I said at the beginning I'm completely new to this.

TIA!

Comment: looks correct. Your data is like that, positively skewed. Perhaps try a log scale on the y axis adding `log = "y"`. Or use histograms.

Comment: Do you have a lot of 0's or very small counts in your data?

Answer (score 0):

As Roman pointed out, your code is correct. The graph look like that because your data is full of zeros. You can get a very similar graph by running the following code:

```
boxplot( c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,10) )
```

Data with inflated zeros looks like this because of the definition of box plot in R: the box covers from the 1st quantile to the third quantile , and the black bar is the median. If most your data is zeros than zeros will be the median and the 1st quantile will be equal, so you would not have a bottom part on your box.

This is expected given your data. I'm not specialized in pollination but I'm guessing a lot of your plants have not being visited by a pollinator, and some where visited by a lot. Might be interesting to remove the unvisited plants from your dataset depending on the question.

Answer (score 0):

To contribute with some forensic, it seems that something like this has happened in your data. The amount of zeros of each `Year` appears to be related (e.g. factor two) with the number of observations somehow.

```
v1 <- cbind(Pollinators=c(rep(0, 3000), 0:1500), Year=1)
v2 <- cbind(Pollinators=c(rep(0, 6000), 0:3000), Year=2)
v3 <- cbind(Pollinators=c(rep(0, 9000), 0:4500), Year=3)
v4 <- cbind(Pollinators=c(rep(0, 12000), 0:6000), Year=4)
v5 <- cbind(Pollinators=c(rep(0, 15000), 0:7500), Year=5)

X_east_pool_park_realistic_results <- rbind(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5)

boxplot(Pollinators~Year, data=X_east_pool_park_realistic_results,
        main=toupper("Pollinators per Year"), font.main=3, cex.main=1.2,
        xlab="Year", ylab="Pollinators", font.lab=3, col="white")
```

[image]

Comment: must not the amount of zeros. The amount of small data points is higher, obviously. Change to e.g. `v1 <- cbind(Pollinators=c(rep(0.1, 3000), 0:1500), Year=1);
v2 <- cbind(Pollinators=c(rep(0.5, 6000), 0:3000), Year=2);
v3 <- cbind(Pollinators=c(rep(1, 9000), 0:4500), Year=3)`